# When will the sequence $k \mapsto A + Bk + k^2$ yield a perfect square?

Tags: sequences-and-series, square-numbers

Consider the following sequence:

$$a(k) = A + Bk + k^2 ,$$

where $A$ and $B$ are both integers, and $A < B$ ($k$ is of course an integer variable, B is even).

Problem:

For which $k^*$ is $a(k^*) = r^2$ (in other words for which $k$ the given sequence will yield a perfect square)?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Yeap, but the thing is that we assume A and B are given. Is there any general method for answering this, regardless of what A and B are?

Comment: Are you looking for a general answer, valid for all $A<B$? Pretty sure such a general answer does not exist.

Comment: Thank you Alex for editing -- I'm a freshman @ Math.Stackexchange and not particularly skilled in LaTeX-like formatting.

Comment: A general solution would be good. But let say I have these particulars A and B -- A = 67290798539959189308492380660371729680847996127544 and B = 156082287421605062049158293357937484075620027600780.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the beginning of a systematic method in the case $B$ even, $B=2B'$:

"Complete the square" i.e., write your expression in the form

$$A'+(B'+k)^2=s^2 \ \ \ \leftrightarrow \ \ \ A'=(s-k-B')(s+k+B')$$

where $A'=A-B'^2$.

You have now to adjust the two parameters $k$ and $s$, but it opens the way for a systematic search by computer.

Comment: Indeed, I should have added this -- in my question B is always even.

Comment: Interesting... I'll try to implement this in C++, but I'm afraid it won't be much of help in case of big integers.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [quadratic Diophantine equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html)
$$
X^2 + B X - Y^2 + A = 0 \quad (*) \\ 
$$
in the unknowns $X, Y$ with $A, B, X, Y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and additional constraints
$$
A < B\\
B \bmod 2 = 0
$$
where the particular $Y$ is not of interest, just that it exists.

Here is a page with [algorithm](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM) and [calculator](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/JQUAD.HTM) for $(*)$. It must then be checked if such solutions honor the additional constraints.

The later introduced condition, that $B$ is even, allows to transform $(*)$ into the simpler equation
$$
X^2 + B X - Y^2 + A = 0 \iff \\
(X + B/2)^2 - Y^2 + A - (B/2)^2 = 0 \iff \\
(X')^2 - Y^2 + (A - (B/2)^2) = 0 \iff \\
(X')^2 - Y^2 = N \quad (**)
$$
with $X' = X + B/2$ and $N = (B/2)^2 - A$.
This is called a generalized Pell's equation (the case $N=1$ is called a Pell's equation), see [here](http://www.jpr2718.org/pell.pdf).

Comment: Of "not of interest" -- means that we simply assume Y = 0 (?)

Comment: No, in general not.You just asked for existence not what perfect square (here: $Y^2$) shows up. If it is zero or whatever depends on the coefficients $A, B$.

Comment: OK, duly noted.

Comment: Looks very promising, but still we have 2 unknown variables and 1 equation. What kind of advantage do we get from transforming one-star into two-stars?

Comment: $(*)$ features a linear term in $X$, $(**)$ not. That seems to be a simpler case. See the links for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

By repeatedly replacing $k$ by either  $k-1,$ or repeatedly by $k+1,$ we can demand that $0 \leq B < 2.$ This will alter $A,$ let us now call it $C.$ This is simply Gauss reduction, if you think in terms of the quadratic form $f(k,j)=k^2 + B k j + A j^2.$

Two sub-problems only:

$$k^2 + C = u^2$$

$$ k^2 + k + C = v^2 $$

$k^2 + C = u^2$ becomes $u^2 - k^2 = C.$ There is at least one solution as long as $C \neq 2 \pmod 4.$ Then write $C = mn,$ with $m \equiv n \pmod 2,$ and then $u-k=m, u+k = n$

$ k^2 + k + C = v^2 $ becomes $4 k^2 + 4k + 4C = 4v^2, $ $4 k^2 + 4k + 1 +(4C - 1 ) = 4v^2, $ $ (2k+1)^2 + (4C-1) = 4v^2. $ Or $  (4C-1) = 4v^2 - (2k+1)^2  $ and. Write all factorings, including negative, for $4C-1 = mn,$ so that $m,n$ are both odd, agree $\pmod 2,$ so we can then solve $2v-2k-1 = m,$ $2v+2k+1 = n.$

Comment: Sorry for not being overwhelmingly wise, but could you explain what you mean by "repeatedly replacing" ?

Comment: @plktrautman, do you know what a binary quadratic form is? I was describing Gauss reduction. As a function of just one variable, this is a translation of the graph, $k \mapsto (k + h)$ for some integer $h$

Comment: Ekhmmm... Gauss reduction, you say ;-)

Comment: @plktrautman if I start with $k^2 + 3 k - 17,$ I can name a new variable $w = k+1,$ so that $k = w - 1,$ and $k^2 + 3 k - 17 = w^2 + w -19.$ Then I go right back and replace with $k,$ to $k^2 + k - 19$

Comment: I understand the transition to the new equation with "w". But how come you go back to the original equation by simply replacing w with k again? It won't be the same equation, right?

Comment: it just  moves the graph left or right. Compare the graphs of $y=x^2$ and $y =(x-1)^2 $

Comment: OK, I can see it. Now how this ties up with your "repeatedly replacing" k with either k-1 or k+1 in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  If you can factor $B^2 - 4A$, there is an effective procedure to find solutions for $k$.

Suppose $A+B+k^2 = r^2$.  Then  $$  k = \frac{1}{2}\left( -B \pm \sqrt{-4A + B^2 + 4 r^2} \right)  \text{.}  $$
Already nicer, no term linear in $k$.  So suppose $-4A + B^2 + 4 r^2 = s^2$.  Then $$  r = \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4A - B^2 + s^2}  \text{.}  $$
Getting simpler...  So suppose $4A - B^2 + s^2 = t^2$.  Then $$  s = \pm\sqrt{-4A + B^2 + t^2}  \text{.}  $$
And we stop, because (1) this is about as simple as this sort of expression can get, (2) continuing two more steps beings us back to this equation, and (3) the next step is pretty much the same (only changes the signs of $4A - B^2$).

Now this last equation says $$  s^2 - t^2 = (s+t)(s-t) = B^2 - 4A  $$
so further progress depends on factorization of $B^2 - 4A$.  This is a common rquirement for solving variants of Pell equations.  (See Hardy, K.; Muskat, J. B.; and Williams, K. S. "[A Deterministic Algorithm for Solving $n=fu^2+gv^2$ in Coprime Integers u and v](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2008809)." Math. Comput. 55, 327-343, 1990.)(See also Robertson, J. "[Solving the generalized Pell equation $x^2 − D y^2 = N$](http://www.jpr2718.org/pell.pdf)".)

For your example in the comments to the Question, you give $A = 67290798539959189308492380660371729680847996127544$ and $B = 156082287421605062049158293357937484075620027600780$.  I don't know how to factor this $B^2 - 4A$, but I can factor it for $A = 67290798539959189308492380660371729680847996127544$ and $B = 15608228742160506204915829335793748$ (which is the same except I've chopped off the tail of $B$).  For this choice, $$
    n = B^2 - 4A = 2^4 \times 17 \times 199039 \times 310867027 \times 1943730433 \times 623415512339964828920869528942638293  
$$ is its factorization into primes.  Cutting this factorizations into pairs $(f, n/f)$, we get 160 pairs, starting with $(1,n)$ and ending with $(390777578750325841604290401088496, 
623415512339964828920869528942638293)$ (sorted by first entry).  The last pair says  \begin{align*}
    s-t &= 390777578750325841604290401088496,  \\
    s+t &= 623415512339964828920869528942638293  
\end{align*} so \begin{align*}
    s &= \frac{1}{2}(390777578750325841604290401088496 + 623415512339964828920869528942638293),  \\
    t &= \frac{1}{2}(623415512339964828920869528942638293 - 390777578750325841604290401088496)  \text{,}
\end{align*} which are not integers.  Eliminating the pairs which don't leave integers for $s$ and $t$, we are left with 96 pairs.  The last of these is $(195388789375162920802145200544248,$ $1246831024679929657841739057885276586)$, so $s = 10623513206734652410381270601542910417$, $t = 10623317817945277247460468456342366169$.  Tracking back through our equations, this gives $$
    r = \pm \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{1253986547076234555535695745438155722542742227874253722939659385796397
0729}
$$ which is again not an integer.  Restricting to pairs that give an integer for $r$, we  are left with 32 pairs.  Restricting to pairs that give an integer for $k$, we are left with one pair and then $k = -15226050279225333588533484146336583979006836353230520139679243607958$.  Your choice of word, "sequence", suggests that you are only interested in $k>0$, so there is no solution of the form you desire for this choice of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Not quite I believe -- A + B * 28775177062023928913461369238354205970422561870 + (28775177062023928913461369238354205970422561870 * 28775177062023928913461369238354205970422561870)  = 2119463013977207107874862537315840534649363085862^2

Comment: @plktrautman : Which $A$ and $B$ are you working with?  Your example $B$ is truncated in my Answer to give something I can factor.  And your proposed $k$ and $r$ do not solve the example in my Answer.  (... where "I can factor" means "factors using software I'm familiar with in less than a few seconds")

Comment: Ah okay, I was referring to my original A and B in earlier comment. So you're testing was made for this truncated B. Clear.